# How to change Automation Status of test case in MTM using c#?

Tags: c#, tfs, mtm

We are trying to integrate UFT scripts with MTM. By far we succeeded in doing so. We have created many applications which uses TFS API and we are comfortable with it.

Question: How can we change the **Automation Status** of a test case?

What we did:

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("Your URL"));
ITestManagementTeamProject project = tfs.GetService<ITestManagementService>().GetTeamProject("Ypur Project Name");
ITestPlan testPlan = project.TestPlans.find("Your test plan ID");
ItestCaseCollection testcasecollection = testPlan.RootSuite.AllTestCases;

foreach (ITestCase testcase in testcasecollection)
{
   if (testcase.Id=="YourTestcaseID")
   {
       //Now here we need tochange status of test case from Not Automated to automated 
       //we can change area path, title ,priority etc using TFS provided methods, but we cant change Automation status from Not Automated to others
       testcase.status="Active"; // to change status of test case from closed to active.

      // What is the method to change Automation status for a test case?? we only find method to get the automation status by using below method which is read only and returns value.
      string str=testcase.IsAutomated(); // this returns but not sets
   }
}
```

So in short do we have any method to change Automation Status of test case in MTM/TFS using C# like we change state and others?

Comment: Do you save the `testcase`?

Comment: which version  of  tfs are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following method:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Associates an automation to the test case.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="testCase">The test case artifact to which to associate automation</param>
    /// <param name="automationTestName">The automation test name. It should be fully
    /// qualified of format "Namespace.ClassName.TestMethodName.</param>
    /// <param name="automationTestType">The automation test type like "CodedUITest".</param>
    /// <param name="automationStorageName">The assembly name containing the above
    /// test method without path like MyTestProject.dll.</param>
    private static ITestCase AssociateAutomation(ITestCase testCase,
        string automationTestName, string automationTestType, string automationStorageName)
    {
        // Build automation guid
        SHA1CryptoServiceProvider crypto = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[16];
        Array.Copy(crypto.ComputeHash(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(automationTestName)), bytes, bytes.Length);
        Guid automationGuid = new Guid(bytes);

        // Create the associated automation.
        testCase.Implementation = testCase.Project.CreateTmiTestImplementation(
                automationTestName, automationTestType,
                automationStorageName, automationGuid);

        // Save the test. If you are doing this for lots of test, you can consider
        // bulk saving too (outside of this method) for performance reason.
        return testCase;
    }
```